# Bash extracting name servers including if they are on new line, using whois

Tags: bash

Hi guys I an trying to extract the name servers from websites but I cant seem to do it if the servers are on a newline e.g. I can do it if its like so....

```
nserver:      ns-a.somesite.com 176.195.2.100  
nserver:      ns-b.somesite.com 176.195.2.101
```

But if it is like this I cant do it:

```
nserver:     
ns-a.somesite.com 176.195.2.100  
ns-b.somesite.com 176.195.2.101
ns-b.somesite.com 176.195.2.102
```

This is what I have so far:

```
whois ebay.com | grep -E "[Ss]ervers{0,1}:"
```

Comment: Not very nice, but `awk -v RS="nserver:" '{print $0}' file` kind of makes it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can I pipe that onto my code so I dont have to read from file. Why is it not nice?

Comment: Sure, just do `whois ebay.com | awk -v RS="nserver:" '{print $0}'`. It is not very nice because there might be some trailing spaces and empty lines in between.

Comment: Ya I done that and unfortunately that provides much more than just the nameservers. The code I have above works fine for ebay.com but other sites that may contain nameserver information on the next line are the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get just the name of the name servers:

```
whois ebay.com | grep -E "Name Server" | tr -d ' ' | awk -F":" '{ print $1 }'
```

You might have to monkey with the grep search criteria depending on what you output looks like, but this should get you 99% of the way there.

Just for reference, this will grep out the lines with "Name Server", it will remove spaces from the line, then it will split the line by a colon and print the second element, which is the name server.

### Updated

Added for the harder example:

```
whois sans.edu | tr -d ' ' | awk -F: '{ if ($1 == "NameServer" && length($2)>0) print $2 ;else if ($0 == "NameServers:") found=1; else if (found == 1 && length($0)>0) print $0; else found=0 }'
```

This one's a bit messier. After removing spaces to make awk happy. In awk we do the following:

- We split by colon.
- If $1 equal "NameServer" and the length $2 > 0 then we print $2 (ebay.com example)
- Else If the line is "NameServers:" (sans.edu example) then we set a flag `found=1`
- Else If the flag is set and the lenght of the line is not 0 then print the line
- Else set the flag to 0 (assuming we have found a 0 character length line)

Comment: Thank you, though it seems very specific to "Name server". This one is a good example of the problem I have here: `whois sans.edu | grep -E "[Ss]ervers{0,1}:"| awk -v RS='' '{print "" $0 "\n"}' `  I cant get the name servers here since they are on the next line. Any ideas on that, I want it to work universally though, it should still work for ebay or any other site.

Comment: Ah! I was using ebay as the example. My helpful answer is no good with sans.edu

Comment: Its the input that counts, so still appreciated!

Comment: Because I'm a glutton for punishment, I rewrote to accomodate both ebay.com and sans.edu. I would imagine you could expand the if/elseif/else.. to pick up other examples as you find them

Comment: That is great man- though a lot more to it than I thought. I may try adjust it so it will take a regex like so `[Ss]ervers{0,1}:` so its more universal- some sites have nserver, nameserver, nameServer & so on. If I can apply the regex I will be getting places. Thanks alot.

Comment: YEa.. I think that might be a good way to go. Just test $1 for that regex in both conditions and you should be golden.